# Django - Supervisor : exited too quickly

Tags: python, django, nginx

I try to deploy my website in Django+Supervisor+NGINX on Ubuntu server 16.04.

Here is my .conf (supervisor):

```
[program:sitepro]
command = /home/user/sitepro/bin/gunicorn sitepro.wsgi:application --bind mywebsite.fr:8002
user = user
autostart = true
autorestart = true
```

My NGINX config file :

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name .mywebsite.fr;
    charset     utf-8;
    root /home/user/sitepro/site/sitepro;
    access_log /home/user/sitepro/site/logs/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /home/user/sitepro/site/logs/nginx/error.log;

    location /static {
        alias /home/user/sitepro/site/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
    }
}
```

When I try to launch gunicorn on the root of my project, everything goes right :

```
(sitepro) user@mybps:~/sitepro/site$ gunicorn sitepro.wsgi:application --bind mywebsite.fr:8002
[2017-11-01 16:09:37 +0000] [1920] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-11-01 16:09:37 +0000] [1920] [INFO] Listening at: http://79.137.39.12:8002 (1920)
[2017-11-01 16:09:37 +0000] [1920] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-11-01 16:09:37 +0000] [1925] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1925
```

I've done a supervisorctrl reread and update (worked).
And if I make supervisorctl status sitepro

```
sitepro                          FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

And if I access my website I've got the "Welcome to Nginx" default page.

I've tried many tutorials for deploy django : I'm lost and tried many things.
Could someone give me a simple and fast tutorial to deploy Django that he used for his propre needings please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that you are missing the `directory=...` in your config file

```
[program:sitepro]
command = /home/user/sitepro/bin/gunicorn sitepro.wsgi:application --bind mywebsite.fr:8002
directory = /home/user/sitepro/site
user = user
autostart = true
autorestart = true
```

Otherwise gunicorn will not know where to find `sitepro.wsgi:application`

Comment: Nice. The app start, but I still got "Welcome to NGINX".

Comment: Seems like you have the default config serving. Look for a file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`. Remove the default config file and then restart nginx. It should work

Comment: Try changing `--bind mywebsite.fr:8002` to `--bind 127.0.0.1:8002`

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -plant`? Also `supervisor tail sitepro`?

Comment: netstat -plant : 
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  

supervisor tail sitepro : ~$ sudo supervisord tail sitepro
Error: positional arguments are not supported: ['tail', 'sitepro']

Do I miss a package ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158009/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-zoloom).

Comment: Tarun find my issue : I forgot to set symbolic link between site-avalaible and site-enabled *headdesk*

Answer (score 6):

To see what is going on, you should log the supervisor output.

To do that, open the supervisor .conf file, and add the following lines:

```
stdout_logfile={Path}
stderr_logfile={Path}
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
```

A possible {Path} could be /home/{youruser}/sitepro.log

Restart supervisor

```
supervisorctl restart sitepro
```

Once restarted, go to the log and tell us what you see.

Comment: Nice idea ! My comment below, I see the same error as Tarun Lalwani.

Comment: using mac m1, did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

in my .conf (supervisor) file:

`command = /home/user/sitepro/bin/gunicorn sitepro.wsgi:application --bind mywebsite.fr:8002`

Double-check the directory path: (`/home/user/sitepro/bin/gunicorn sitepro.wsgi:application`)

You may have inputted the **incorrectly path**